# How to make the format 2015-09-04T11:30:06-0500 to 2015-09-04T11:30:06-05:00 in SimpleDateFormat

Tags: java

Used the below code and not getting the exact output.

Desired output:

```
2015-09-04T11:30:06-0500 to 2015-09-04T11:30:06-05:00
```

Actual output:

```
dateValue => 2015-10-19T16:52:23-0400
a => 2015-10-20T02:22:23+0530
```

My code:

```
public class test {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String a = formattedDate("2015-10-19T16:52:23-0400");
        System.out.println  ("a => " + a);
    }

    public static String formattedDate (String dateValue) {
        String expectedFormat = "";
        SimpleDateFormat inputDateFormat =
                new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ");
        SimpleDateFormat outputDateFormat =
                new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZZ");

        try {
            System.out.println("dateValue => " + dateValue);
            if (dateValue == null || dateValue.isEmpty()) {
                dateValue = "";
            }
            inputDateFormat.setLenient(true);
            Date d = inputDateFormat.parse(dateValue);
            expectedFormat = outputDateFormat.format(d);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // Sending back the current datetime in the desired format
            Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
            expectedFormat = outputDateFormat.format(cal.getTime());
        }

         return expectedFormat;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Under Java 7 and higher, you can use `XXX` to output the time zone with a column:

```
SimpleDateFormat outputDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssXXX");
```

When you use this to format a data, it will return for example:

```
2001-07-04T12:08:56-07:00
```

See the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) for more examples.

Comment: Thanks for the help Thomas. But issue is with the version. I'm using 1.6

Comment: okay, I added the fact that you need to use Java 8. I will just leave this here for future visitors. :)

Answer (score 1):

Since I'm using 1.6, XXX is not supported. So used alternative way to achieve this. This is what I did for alternative way..

```
public static String formattedDate (String dateValue) {
        StringBuilder expectedFormat;
        SimpleDateFormat inputDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ");
        try {
            if (dateValue == null || dateValue.isEmpty()) {
                dateValue = "";
            }
            inputDateFormat.setLenient(false);
            Date d = inputDateFormat.parse(dateValue);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error in parsing : " + e.getMessage());
            // Sending back the current datetime in the desired format
            Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
            dateValue = inputDateFormat.format(cal.getTime());          
        } finally {
            expectedFormat = new StringBuilder(dateValue).insert(dateValue.length()-2, ":");
        }       
        return expectedFormat.toString();       
    }
```

Comment: Don't waste your time, use `FastDateFormat` from Commons Lang.

Answer (score 1):

When you need only the third last character changed and give a string as a parameter how about leaving it a String?

```
public static String formattedDate (String dateValue)
{
    return dateValue.substring(0, dateValue.length() - 2) 
            + ":"
            + dateValue.substring(dateValue.length() - 2);
}

Output:
a => 2015-10-19T16:52:23-04:00
```